# A not very easy puzzle with an easy answer. Something that a grim puzzler might like

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

1f411

pirate gibberish

00000010

1f607

.

1f441

1f44f

1f411

.

Cigarette ___

lion's-bane@

ワs

22 2

65 61 73 79

160 141 162 164

"2" & right(getMethod("mixintowater"), 5)

9 (4*2) 2 8 _ (4*3) (7*4) _ 6 (9*3) _ (6*2) 2 6 (3*2)?

Hint:

> Unicode, guess, binary, Unicode - Unicode, Unicode, Unicode - guess, guess+symbols,Japanese,chemistry, ASCII, ASCII, code - ...

Comment: Did we ever find out what the business about the "grim puzzler" was?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan grim = Grimm as in Grimm fairy tales, as in Rumpelstiltskin who asks the same final question...

Comment: Ah! I did wonder about Grimm but had forgotten that feature of Rumpelstiltskin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line is a telephone cipher.

A regular telephone keypad looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     | ABC | DEF |
|     |     |     |
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| GHI | JKL | MNO |
|     |     |     |
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| PQRS| TUV | WXYZ|
|     |     |     |
|  7  |  8  |  9  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|  *  |  0  |  #  |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Given a character in the code, if there is just a single number (e.g. 2), you press that key once, to give the first letter on that number (i.e. A). If the character is a number "times" some other `n` (e.g. "7*4"), you press the key `n` times to get the `n`th letter for that number (i.e. S).

Doing so, you get the message:

> WHAT IS MY NAME?

Which is, of course, **Brent Hackers**.

Comment: You got it.  Well done. +1  I feel like I'll be hated for this one (sorry Garreth).

Comment: I've seen enough puzzles like that to know to think of that first when I saw that specific pattern. :P

Comment: Although good job misleading everybody into thinking that the first part of the puzzle had anything to do with the last part. That part might be the one that _really_ makes people angry.

Comment: Some might call it cruelty... I feel suitably bad about it though, honnest I do gov'!

Comment: Well done, Joe! Not so well done, Brent, for making a puzzle almost all of which has nothing at all to do with the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The first half's easy enough. It says something like

> EWE ARRR TWO GOOD. EYE APPLAUD EWE.
>  (i.e. "You are too good. I applaud you.")

The second half seems to be something like

> BUTT THAT WAS THE EASY PART TO SOLVE ____?

where

> BUTT is obvious; the lion's bane is *thorn* (thanks to hexomino in comments) which of course means TH; the Japanese character is the hiragana "wa" making WAS; the elements are TiHe which I guess are meant to signify "the" (there being no element T); interpreting 65 etc. as hex codes for ASCII characters we get EASY; interpreting 161 etc. as *octal* codes for ASCII characters we get PART (all credit to hexomino in comments); perhaps "mixintowater" is meant to signify "dissolve" yielding "2solve" or "to solve"; and the last bit currently mystifies me.

So the remaining mystery is

> the final numerical thing, where I have no idea what's going on nor whether the use of things like "(4*2)" in preference to "8" is a red herring, a clue, or an important actual difference. These all seem to be nice small numbers with nice small factors, but what pattern they follow I don't know.

I also don't know

> what exactly the title signifies. "An easy answer": well, the word "easy" appears to be part of the answer, but surely that isn't all. "a grim puzzler": no idea what's going on there, though apparently there's a computer game called Grim Fandango with a lot of puzzles in it.

Comment: Not a bad start.  +1

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan A lion's bane could be a thorn (which is old English "th")

Comment: Also 160 141 162 164 is "part" converted from octal to ASCII

Comment: Oh you very clever person. Yes. (I already even mentioned thorns, but forgot about the letter.)

Comment: Octal. Aargh. I am feeling very stupid.

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't help you that much because I have no idea about the last bit. +1 for what you've got so far.

Comment: It clearly needs to be 3 letters and to fit into that already-complete-looking sentence. I wonder whether it will end up being something like LOL. (Or 101 with the same meaning.)

Comment: ... oh, except that whatever it is there needs to be a *question mark* at the end of the sentence, which is kinda weird and I suspect very informative if I were infinitely intelligent.

Comment: (or maybe the question mark is somehow part of the sequence rather than part of the sentence we're constructing)

Comment: Seems like you solved the better part of this one.  Well done.

Comment: Good call on the octal heximino. +1

Comment: Joe Z really swooped in at the last sec with the answer.  You were spot on about all the rest though.  The +1 that I give to you is as big and important as 10 regular +1s

Comment: Apparently "the better part" means "the part that has no bearing at all on the actual answer".

Comment: Better as in most of... And yes... sorry about that.