# what's in a name but a few letters hidden behind words?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> the first of mine will complete your message 
>   the second of mine will finish your school book 
>   the third of mine you can feel free to accept 
>   the fourth of mine will never be high or low, but it will be the end 
>   the fifth of mine will feed you lines that will always feel fresh

what is my name?

**Hint #1**

> The Knowledge required is computer related.

Comment: Could be ASCII codes ... ?

Comment: @friedemann_bach Could be :P

Comment: Several of the lines certainly look that way. I'm having trouble seeing how they fit together, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Keep in mind that I'm asking what is my name.

Comment: Oh, damn, so you are. (The text editor in which I was scribbling notes ended with this: "letter indices D C E/F Y J which doesn't seem very hopeful". I really am a moron.)

Comment: I thought it was fairly clever. All these riddles about famous folks, why not a not-so-famous person :P

Comment: You will see why I'm annoyed at missing this one if you take a look at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35655/a-not-very-easy-puzzle-with-an-easy-answer-something-that-a-grim-puzzler-might from a few days ago. Take especial note of what the final question of that one turned out to be.

Comment: (for the avoidance of doubt, the annoyance is all at myself, not at you!)

Comment: I remember seeing that question, never looked at the answer though, haha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each line clues

> A C0 control character.

the first of mine will complete your message

> End of Transmission (^D)

the second of mine will finish your school book

> End of Text (^C)

the third of mine you can feel free to accept

> Acknowledge (^F)

the fourth of mine will never be high or low, but it will be the end

> End of Medium (^Y)

the fifth of mine will feed you lines that will always feel fresh

> Line Feed (^J)

Together they make (thanks to @quidam)

> dcfyj, which is OP's username.

Comment: Definitely on the right track, just a little more and you have the answer the my question.

Answer (score 4):

Completing the answer of f'':

> The five letters they found form the name of the OP (dcfyj).

Comment: Correct. Although now I don't know who exactly to credit with the correct answer check mark...

Comment: Definitely f''.  I would have posted as a comment, but wasn't sure if I could "spoilerize" it.

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely giving you a +1. Would give you both the mark if I could.