# #When money speaks#

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

```
        #  #              #  #              #  #              #  #             #  #    
     #        #        #        #        #        #        #        #       #        #
    #  8       #      #    4     #      #  2       #      #    6     #     #     5    #
    #          #      #          #      #          #      #          #     #          #
     #        #        #        #        #        #        #        #       #        #
        #  #              #  #              #  #              #  #             #  #     

                      #  #              #  #              #  #           #  #             #  #  
                   #        #        #        #        #        #     #        #       #        #
                  #       Y* #      #        6 #      #     8    #   #       3  #     #        6 #      
                  #          #      #          #      #          #   #          #     #          #     
                   #        #        #        #        #        #     #        #        #       #        
                      #  #              #  #              #  #          #  #              #  #              

            #  #              #  #              #  #              #  #   
         #        #        #        #        #        #        #        #
        #     R*   #      #    S*    #      #        6 #      #        5 #
        #          #      #          #      #          #      #          #
         #        #        #        #        #        #        #        #
            #  #              #  #              #  #              #  #       

                  #  #              #  #              #  #             #  #              #  #   
               #        #        #        #        #        #       #        #        #        #
              #        8 #      #        4 #      #     6    #     # 4        #      # 8        #
              #          #      #          #      #          #     #          #      #          #
               #        #        #        #        #        #       #        #        #        #
                  #  #              #  #              #  #             #  #               #  #               

                  #  #              #  #              #  #   
               #        #        #        #        #        #
              #     4    #      #         4#      #     S*   #
              #          #      #          #      #          #
               #        #        #        #        #        #
                  #  #              #  #              #  #
```

I just dropped a few coins. They have a message for you. Oh and one more thing, a clue rests in the title if you don't get it :-)

**Can you find it?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbers are

> telephone keypad numbers corresponding to letters

and the asterisked letters are

> to be interpreted literally.

The clue in the title is

> threefold: a reference to the # key on a phone, to the fact that you put coins into payphones, and (of course) to the fact that you speak on the phone.

The message is

> THANK YOU FOR SOLVING THIS.

Comment: I mean, i spent over an hour trying to figure this out and you make it so simple. what is life

Comment: Was there a deliberate reason for the locations of numbers within their circles or no?

Comment: @n_palum yes, but can't explain in a comment because of spoilers. But if you think about the answer that Gareth wrote and you have a bit of imagination you can figure it out by yourself

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia Oh I get it now.. I thought it would've been clever to have them located as if you were using one of the old spinning wheel payphones.

Comment: @n_palum That could have made it a little trivial and off-course a [tag:knowledge] would have been required :)

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia Sorry! If it makes you feel any better, take a look at [my first encounter with this sort of cipher](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35655/a-not-very-easy-puzzle-with-an-easy-answer-something-that-a-grim-puzzler-might) where I spent ages solving 90% of a puzzle ... whose final answer turned out to be one of these and to make no use at all of the earlier bits I'd spent all that time on.

Comment: @Techidiot Meh I guess so.. It's the thought process I was on so I guess I kind of got what you were going for ;)

Comment: You won 89 worth of coins and 15+ :-) Nice solve